# django search string in string

Tags: django, google-app-engine

can we search string in another string/list/array in django which is passed through python template. Thanks in adv...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few methods for searching a string within a string, like `string.find`, `string.rfind`, `string.index` and `string.rindex`. Here you can find documentation about them:

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

If doesn't matter if the strings were created using a template...

Comment: I _think_ he's asking how to do a substring match on a string inside a Django template - but it's very difficult to tell.